# Como puedo saber cuantas veces se repite un dato en una consulta sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Buenas Tardes Quiero saber como sacar el numero de veces que se repite un tipo de dato y llevarlo a una tabla con php en estos momentos tengo el siguiente código pero no se como extraer el numero de veces que se repite un dato en esta consulta

este es el código:

```
$rs1 = mssql_query("SELECT vendedor, nombre FROM vendedor WHERE clasificacion = '1' GROUP BY vendedor, nombre ORDER BY nombre ASC", $link);
    while ($row1 = mssql_fetch_row($rs1)){
        echo "<tr value='$row1[0]'><td>$row1[1]</td></tr>";
}
$rs= mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT codigo_vendedor, estado,COUNT(*) as total FROM pedidos WHERE codigo_vendedor = '$row1[0]' AND DATE_FORMAT(fecha_pedido, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '$fecha_desde' AND '$fecha_hasta' GROUP BY estado");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs)){
      //echo "fguyhkglfjsdojgdsfkljfgknlhlkj";

            $row[0] == $row1[0];                    
            if ($row[1] == 'Logistica') {
                $row[1] = $log; 
            }elseif ($row[1] == 'Picking') {
                $row[1] = $pic;
            }elseif ($row[1] == 'Facturado') {
                $row[1] = $fac;              
            }elseif ($row[1] == 'Packing') {
                $row[1] = $pac;
            }elseif ($row[1] == 'Cartera') {
                $row[1] = $car;
            }elseif(strpos($row[1], 'Facturacion') !== false){
      $row[1] = $fact;
        }
       }
?>
 </tr>
 <td><?php echo $row1[2]?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row[3]?></td>
 <td><?php echo $log?></td>
 <td><?php echo $car?></td>
 <td><?php echo $fact?></td>
 <td><?php echo $pic?></td>
 <td><?php echo $fac?></td>
 <td><?php echo $pac?></td>
```

Estaría muy Agradecido Con su ayuda

Comment: Con tipo de dato te refieres a contar cuantas veces hay un string, entero ? O te refieres a saber cuantas veces se repite por ejemplo una palabra en los registros

Comment: me refiero a saber cuantas veces se repite una palabra en los registros

Comment: `select estado Count(estado) from pedidos   group by estado? `

Comment: Dev. Joel si te fijas bien en la consulta esta definido de esa manera pidiendo claro esta otros datos de la tabla pedidos

Comment: Usa un count en tu consulta que te retornara la cantidad de vecez que aparece un registro no tienes que recorrer array para ver esto ya que tendrias un On mayor

Comment: Si solo necesitas el numero de veces que un dato se repite puedes utilizar count

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La cantidad que se repite un dato  la trae tu consulta ya no es necesario tener `if else` , el código quedaria algo así, ya modificado para que se muestre en una `tabla`

```
$rs= mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT  estado,COUNT(estado) as total FROM pedidos WHERE codigo_vendedor = '$row1[0]' AND DATE_FORMAT(fecha_pedido, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '$fecha_desde' AND '$fecha_hasta' GROUP BY estado");
     echo "<table><thead><tr><th>Estado</th><th>Cantidad</th></tr></thead <tbody>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs)){
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row[0] . "</td><td>". $row[1]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody></table>"
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Esta consulta te devuelve el numero de registro duplicado en tu tabla

```
   SELECT vendedor, nombre, count(*) As Reg_Duplicados FROM vendedor  GROUP BY vendedor, nombre Having Count(*) >1
```

Answer (score 1):

Es ejemplo sencillo es hacerte un contador inicializado en 0.

```
$cont = 0;
```

Y una vez dentro del while haces la busqueda

```
if($dato == "tuPalabra") {
    $cont++;
}
```

Y si quieres tener varios contadores usas un switch

```
switch($dato) {
    case "palabra1":
        $cont1++;
         break;
    case  "palabra2":
        $cont2++;
        break;
}
```

El dato obviamente sería tu row["campo"]

Luego tambien puedes por medio de la consulta sql